# many to many relationship error in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

> i have **two tables**,

1) **qualifs**

2)  **teachers**

one teacher can have many qualifications

i created

pivot table; **qualif_teacher**

with two columns (**teacher_id** & **qualif_id**)

when i am saving teacher info, `teachers qualifications are saving correctly with multiple ids`, my **problem** is i am getting error when i try to view any teachers qualification in my blade file.

> **error:** Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

**Route:** /teachers

**Index Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
  $teachers= DB::table('teachers')
  $qualifs = DB::table('qualifs')->find($teachers);
return view('teachers.index',compact('teachers','qualifs'));
}
```

**Edit Controller:**

```
public function edit($id)
  {
    $qualifs = DB::table('qualifs')->find($id);
      $teacher = Teacher::find($id);
      return response()->json([
          'status' => 'success',
          'teacher' => $teacher,
          'qualifs'=>$qualifs,
      ]);

  }
```

**View:**

```
@if(isset($teachers))
  @foreach($teachers->qualifs as $qualif)
      <li>{{ $qualif->qual }}</li>
      @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you pass the variable $teachers in your find function, but find always expects int number to execute his process. Thats why you are getting this error.

So try to replace this

```
public function index()
{
  $teachers= DB::table('teachers')
  $qualifs = DB::table('qualifs')->find($teachers);
return view('teachers.index',compact('teachers','qualifs'));
}
```

with this code

```
public function index()
    {
      $teacher= Teacher::with('qualifs')->first();
      foreach($teacher->qualifs as $ qualif)
     {
         $qualiflist[]=$qualif->name;
     }
    dd($qualiflist);
    return view('teachers.index',compact('teacher','qualifs'));
    }
```

that should be solve your problem

Comment: Property [qualifs] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: then probably you are actually trying to find the qualifs table id which is equal to teacher id and it is not present in your table that why you are getting this error

Comment: record which i am trying to show has, qualif_id 1 and teacher_id 740 in qualif_teacher table.

Comment: that's mean you vae belongsToMany relation between user and qualif?Am i right

Comment: if i rigth then see my edited answer, it might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
return view('teachers.index',compact('teachers','$qualifs'));
```

to

```
return view('teachers.index',compact('teachers','qualifs'));
```

You added `$` and it dosen't work like this.

And in your view

```
@if(isset($teachers))
@foreach($teachers->qualifs as $qualif)
<li>{{ $qualif->qual }}</li>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Did you update the view? instead of `teacher` you should make it `teachers`

Comment: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Try to replace the `foreach` with this `@if(isset($teachers))
@foreach($teachers as $qualif)
<li>{{ $qualif->qualifs->qual }}</li>
@endforeach
@endif`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201464/discussion-between-eyad-jaabo-and-fayakon).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on your controller

```
//Please ensure you import the both related models on the top of your controller
 use App\Qualifs;
 use App\Teacher;

      public function edit($id)
      {
        $teacher = Teacher::find($id); //if the id edit is accepting belongs to the teacher model 
        return $teacher->qualifs()->get(); //this should return all qualifications for this particular teacher so far as the relationships are set

        $qualifs = Qualifs::find($id); //if the id edit is accepting belongs to the Qualif model
         return $qualifs->teachers()->get(); //this should return all teachers for this particular qualifications so far as the relationships are set
      }
```